# Error in Sending captured image from Java to Android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have the code to capture image from screen in java, I have the final captured image as BufferedImage object and Can cast it to ImageIcon

The problem is when sending that file to android can't read it as bitmap drawable. Any one have answer to this ?

Code to send (Java)

```
            BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);

        //Send captured screen to the server
        try {
            System.out.println("before sending image");      

            oos.writeObject(imageIcon);
            oos.reset(); //Clear ObjectOutputStream cache
            System.out.println("New screenshot sent");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Android Receiver Part

```
Thread t= new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {


                try {

                    client= sc.accept();
                    is = client.getInputStream();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                BitmapDrawable imageIcon = null;

                try {
                    ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
                    imageIcon = (BitmapDrawable) ois.readObject();
                    //Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
                    IV.setImageDrawable(imageIcon);
                } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("New image recieved");


            }

        }
```

I get the exception of it can't cast the imageIcon or the BufferedImage to Bitmap drawable.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use objects, because oracle jvm is not the same as android's dalvik.
Try to convert captured image to raw bytes and send those bytes to android. Then in android covert this raw data to drawable.